# How can I override apache solr's default search result sorting?

Tags: 6, search

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026147/how-are-the-apache-solr-search-results-sequenced), search results are ordered by relevance score. How can I override this? I want our results sorted by created date. I'm not talking about allowing users to sort by different fields, just the default order of results returned by apache solr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This requires a custom modules where you implement a hook provided by apachesolr. There are several options but `hook_apachesolr_modify_query(&$query, &$params, $caller)` works as well as any.

You can modify the `$query`:

```
$query->set_solrsort($field_name, $direction);
```

Or you can modify the `$params`:

```
$params['sort'] = "$field_name $direction";
```

Comment: Since apachesolr-7.x-1.0-beta6 the hook changed to `hook_apachesolr_query_alter($query)`